# How do I fix error HY000, 'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameter s were supplied' in below code? I am using Tkinter

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

*Edited per request:

How do I fix the attached error in the code below?  If I take #UPDATE RECORD section out, everything works fine.  The update statement to the database makes it puke.  The code below will work, but the call to the mdb has been removed for security.  Also, the primary key for the mdb is the "user" name.  Any and all help greatly appreciated:

```
def update_record():
    #GRAB THE RECORD NUMBER
    selected = my_tree.focus()
    #UPDATE RECORD
    my_tree.item(selected, text="", values=(casr_entry.get(), fn_entry.get(), loc_entry.get(), draw1_entry.get(), draw2_entry.get(), draw3_entry.get(), superv_check.get(), create_check.get(), void_check.get(), active_check.get(), recon_check.get(), drwer_check.get(), ))

    #UPDATE THE DATABASE
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=\\<CONNECT TO DATABASE LOCATION HERE>.mdb;')
    c = conn.cursor()    

    c.execute("""UPDATE Users SET
        active = :active,
        
        fullname = :fn,
        location = :loc,
        create = :create,
        supervisor = :superv,
        void_rights = :void,
        reconcile = :recon,
        drawers = :drwer,
        drawer1 = :draw1,
        drawer2 = :draw2,
        drawer3 = :draw3
        
        WHERE user = :casr""",
        {
            'active': active_check.get(),
            'casr': casr_entry.get(),
            'fn': fn_entry.get(),
            'loc': loc_entry.get(),
            'create': create_check.get(),
            'superv': superv_check.get(),
            'void': void_check.get(),
            'recon': recon_check.get(),
            'drwer': drwer_check.get(),
            'draw1': draw1_entry.get(),
            'draw2': draw2_entry.get(),
            'draw3': draw3_entry.get(),
        })

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I have tried many different variations to update the record, via research and code to no avail.  I am wanting the database to update with the new/adjusted information to keep it current.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code sample down. If the problem is with a sql statement, we probably don't need any of the tkinter code since sql doesn't care where the data comes from.

Comment: Will do.  Was told previously to include a minimum working code, so was confused on what to include.  Apologies.

Comment: Yes, we need minimum working code. That means it still needs to be working, but we need the fewest lines possible to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The section edited is the only part of my code not working.  If I need to adjust further, I would be happy to do so.

Comment: pyodbc doesn't use `:name` placeholders. You have to use `?` and put the value in a list or tuple.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  I will review.  Greatly appreciate.